# .AddMvc() in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am migrating an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application over to 3.0, and have a clarification question on .AddMvc(). My Application uses Razor Pages and Views, if that's important.

So currently, I have the following in the 2.2 code:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            })
           .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

The [Migration Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration) say that "AddMvc continues to behave as it has in previous releases." But, then it goes on to say that the following is "the same thing as .AddMvc() in 2.2":

```
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();
```

Therefore, my question is, which one should I use?

My approach is to do something like:

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
             {
                 options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
              })
              .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

Would this be the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: `AddMvc()` is really just a wrapper around a bunch of other methods that register services. It's just a quick way of bootstrapping a typical app. If you want to not include certain things or customize how things are registered, then you can use the individual methods instead. See: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0303c9e90b5b48b309a78c2ec9911db1812e6bf3/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, I believe that you would set the Razor page options in the `.AddRazorPages()` call like so:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages(options => 
{
    options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

I'm not certain the `.SetCompatibilityVersion()` is necessary, but according to the Intellisense that you can hang it off of either the `.AddControllersWithViews()` or `.AddRazorPages()` call.

Comment: Alright, thank you! So, it is best practice to not use `.AddMvc()` in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell from the migration docs and new templates.  It seems to have been superseded.

Comment: What you have looks good.  Calling SetCompatibilityVersion on one is same as on both, it's an idempotent call on services.  .AddMvc() in fact is simply a method that internally calls both of these.  So, matter of opinion on whether you want to call it, if only calling one of these you certainly wouldn't.